# Re Duplicates in Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, duplicates, max

I have a requirement to include Student details along with Postcode and Borough in my query.

Query gives correct results when I include the Postcode.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
 t1.StuID,
 t1.Forename,
 t1.Surname,
 t1.dob,
 t2.a_reference "Postcode",
  FROM
student t1, address t2
WHERE t1.s_address = t2.a_id

O/P:

AC24340 MITCHELL ACKERMAN     21-OCT-99    N1 1HH 
AB48765 KEANUE   SETTLE       17-JUL-97    N19 4EU
```

However, When I add the Borough field I see duplicates as below

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
     t1.StuID,
     t1.Forename,
     t1.Surname,
     t1.dob,
     t2.a_reference "Postcode",
     MAX(t.el_name) "Borough" -- Using Max so as to get most recent value for Borough
     FROM
    student t1, address t2, lookup t3
    WHERE 
 WHERE t1.s_address = t2.a_id AND
    t2.a_reference (+) = t3.el_reference
     GROUP BY t1.StuID, t1.Forename, t1.Surname,
     t1.dob, t2.a_reference, t3.el_name

O/P:

AC24340 MITCHELL ACKERMAN     21-OCT-99    N1 1HH          Barnsbury
AC24340 MITCHELL ACKERMAN     21-OCT-99    N1 1HH          Islington
AB48765 KEANUE   SETTLE       17-JUL-97    N19 4EU         Tollington
AB48765 KEANUE   SETTLE       17-JUL-97    N19 4EU         Islington
```

Any idea where am I going wrong?

Thanks
Ar

Comment: Would you please add table structures in your question and some sample data of the tables ?

Comment: We see a date i the results, but no date column is shown in the queries. It is necessary to know more about your tables and data than you have given us.

Answer (score 1):

should remove the   `t3.el_name` from group by

```
   SELECT 
     t1.StuID,
     t2.a_reference "Postcode",
     MAX(t.el_name) "Borough" -- Using Max so as to get most recent value for Borough
     FROM
    student t1, address t2, lookup t3
    WHERE 
 WHERE t1.s_address = t2.a_id AND
    t2.a_reference (+) = t3.el_reference
     GROUP BY t1.StuID,
     t2.a_reference
```

Comment: by the way, no need to use "DISTINCT" in above query.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan   correct .. distinct removed (there is group by)  many thanks

Answer (score 1):

MAX() does NOT give "most recent" value, it returns the maximum, which could be "Westminster" even if the person is currently addressed at "Barking".

Please stop using commas between table names in the FROM clause. Over 25 years ago (ANSI-92) better join syntax was adopted as standard.

If you are using GROUP BY then "select distinct" is 100% utterly useless and redundant. GROUP BY ensure the rows are unique by itself, it does not need "select distinct" as well (plus, GROUP BY is performed before the "select distinct").

To get the "most recent" address you need to reference the date field that we see in results shown in the question, but which isn't listed in ether query. Take that table and make it a subquery instead. In that subquery use ROW_NUMBER() OVER().

*The following is a GUESS because the details of your tables aren't revealed in the question. I am not expecting this suggested query to work "as is" - it will need to be "interpreted".*

```
SELECT
      t1.StuID
    , t2.a_reference "Postcode"
    , t.el_name "Borough" 
FROM student t1
INNER JOIN (
      SELECT
            a_reference
          , date_of_address_change
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a_reference
                               ORDER BY date_of_address_change DESC) AS rn
      FROM address
      ) t2 ON t1.s_address = t2.a_id AND rn = 1
LEFT JOIN lookup t3 ON t2.a_reference = t3.el_reference
```

Using order by inside the OVER() we can locate a "most recent" row and then return only that row by the "AND RN = 1" of the join to the subquery.